# "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" while using mvn -v

Tags: java, maven

I changed java 7 to java 6 after that maven stoped work. I install java 6, changed all Environment variables, delete java.exe from system32 and even after that I get this "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". I have to use java 6. How to fix maven?

Comment: You just clean and install

Comment: I'm not even build a project. Maven doesn't work at all

Comment: You still have some java executables on your path? What do you see if you run `java -version`? or `"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java" -version`

Comment: `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Which maven version do you use?

Comment: Maven 3.3.X needs Java 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Maven 3.3 or newer, Java 7 is required. So make sure, you use a Maven version older than that (e.g. 3.2.x).

Alternatively you can use Maven 3.3.x with Java 7 and configure toolchains to compile your project with Java 6: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Answer (score 0):

You have jars which contain code for Java 7, most likely in your repository.  Try deleting it.

```
rm -r ~/.m2/repository
```

Comment: @cadmy correct.  Maven itself uses a local repo. It downloads most of itself and runs it from there.